# Check if file exists in any directory in path or if current directory is in a git project

Tags: bash, git, shell, zsh

I'm working on adding a short command to my `.zshrc` file that will call `clear`, `ls`, and `git status`. The `git status` command should only be called if the current directory is part of a git project.

So far I have a version that works, but only if the `.git` file is actually in the current directory, so only in the root directory of the project. That looks like this:

```
alias cl="clear && ls && if [ -e .git ]
then
    git status
fi"
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if there is a `.git` file in any parent directory of the current directory—or if there's another way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to check if there exists a `.git` directory.  Git *already does this for you*. If you want to know whether your current directory is part of a git repository, just run:

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
```

The exit code will tell you whether your in a directory that is part of a git repository.  That makes your alias look something like:

```
alias cl="clear && ls && if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> /dev/null
then
  git status
fi"
```

Comment: I would note that this would be much more readable as a function rather than an alias, and would be called in an identical way.